# How to analyse such circuit with op amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, circuit-analysis

[image: Circuit]

V(вх) is input voltage, I need to find output voltage(in the center). Yeah, it must be amplifier, of course. Just, I know and understand how to calculate simple non-inverting, inverting circuits with negative feedback. Can you, please, give me good examples (or links, books where to read) of, maybe, circuit with two op amps, how to calculate them?

P.S. It is Russian circuit, so rectangles are resistors here ;)

Comment: The circuit diagram makes no sense. Eg. it looks like you are driving the power supply of A3 from A1 and A2. And what is `B`? What does `+97B, (98B)` mean? Otherwise it looks a bit like a bridge amplifier.

Comment: @jippie - What don't you get? It makes sense to me, at least somewhat. A1 and A2 *are* driving the power supplies to A3. It looks like its some funky sort of rail-switching, in an attempt to reduce the dissipation in A3 by spreading the dissipation around. It also lets them pull off ~200V Peak-Peak output with 100V rated op-amps.

Comment: There is no center. The schematic is symmetric around a 7.5k resistor. Is your output in a center tap of the resistor?

Comment: I'm assuming that "B" is russian for "V", or voltage. \$R_{H}\$ is presumably the load they are driving, and since it's driven in a bridge configuration, it achieves ~400V P-P. What is this for, anyways? I would guess ultrasonics or something.

Comment: It's interesting that if a voltage ("B") is not marked with a `+`, it seems it's assumed to be negative, whereas everything I've seen, if it's not marked with a `-`, it's assumed to be positive.

Comment: Yeah, guys, "B" is "Вольт" (Voltage). I will translate some more info, that was decribing picture in this [page](http://www.kit-e.ru/articles/usil/2008_08_68.php) :
"Bridge consist of 6 op amps OPA454 with supply voltage +-100V and range of output voltage of 390 V. Circuit made of inverting and non-inverting amlifiers, which shown in a fig.7. Two pictures below showing time diagrams of this amplifier on a load 7.5 kOhm with a freq. 20 kHz..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing outside your experience here. A3 is a simple noninverting amplifier with a gain of +20, and A4 is a simple inverting amplifier with a gain of -20. Since the load is briged across the two ouptuts, the overall gain is the difference: +20 – (–20) = +40.

The rest of the opamps are creating "tracking" power supplies for the two signal amplifiers, such that none of the six amplifiers ever has more than about 100 V across it. However, the bridged load sees a voltage of up to 400 V<sub>PP</sub> across it (with a 10 V<sub>PP</sub> input signal).

Each of the opamps A1, A2, A5 and A6<sup>[1]</sup> is configured as a voltage follower, and each is driven by a 50-50 voltage divider between one of the power supplies and the output of the corresponding signal amplifier. When the signal amplifier's output changes by any given amount, its positive and negative power supplies are each shifted by half that amount. When the output signal is zero, the power supplies for A3 and A4 are at ±50 V. When either output signal swings to +100V, its power supplies shift to +100 and –0 V, and when it swings to –100 V, the power supplies are +0 and –100 V.

<sup>[1]</sup> Actually, the given schematic has two amplifiers labeled "A4", but work with me here.

Comment: Is this effect of positive feedback, when we set voltage of power supply pins to be the function of input voltage?

Comment: In the original TI circuit one of the erroneously labelled A4 amplifiers is labelled A6.

Comment: What is potentially confusing here is suspecting the possibility of some kind of feedback interaction between the voltage rail action and the inputs. But in fact that is separable. Regardless of where the rails are at any given moment, they can be ignored from the perspective of understanding what A3 and A4 are doing, which depends only on the differential voltage at the inputs, and the feedback network. Any relation of that to the absolute power rail position is common mode (and so, ideally, nonexistent).